# Midnight Commander is showing some weird characters

Tags: 11.04

I have no idea why this happens, how do i fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little more information would be nice. Its obvious that the â is being used as borders and something is odd. A quick look online for changing the character being used as a border  suggests that your character set is incorrect and you need to change it to UTF-8([source](http://www.andremiller.net/content/getting-midnight-commander-line-drawing-work-putty)), and you're probably using putty

[image]